# PHP html special characters encode not to entities but Decimal

Tags: php, encoding, decimal, html-entities

I have trouble finding a solution for the following problem:

I have a lot of special characters on the website that when I run them through htmlentities();

you get all the special characters converted to HTML entities:

```
£ => &pound;
" => &quot;
Â => &Acirc;
....
```

But what I actually need is the Decimal version of that encoding:

```
£ => &#163;
" => &#34;
&Acirc; of(Â) => &#192;
&nbsp; => &#160;
```

Is there a function that already exists that would solve this issue without doing this manually with a replace?

Comment: I'm curious for what problem this is a solution? Maybe another solution can be found so you don't need this?

Comment: I'm creating a XML feed and I need valid characters so it would be W3C compliant, if decimal encoding is used then I never get any problems but if normal htmlcharacter encoding is used then it doesnt valdate

Comment: Are you referring to this problem? http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/01/02/xmlchar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
function htmlnumericentities($str){ 
  return preg_replace('/[^!-%\x27-;=?-~ ]/e', '"&#".ord("$0").chr(59)', $str); 
} 

function numericentitieshtml($str){ 
  return utf8_encode(preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/e', 'chr(str_replace(";","",str_replace("&#","","$0")))', $str)); 
} 

echo (htmlnumericentities ("Ceci est un test : & é $ à ç <")); 
echo ("<br/>\n"); 
echo (numericentitieshtml (htmlnumericentities ("Ceci est un test : & é $ à ç <")));
```

Comment: Hi the htmlnumericentities() is perfect for what I need but numericentitieshtml() has a small issue you enclosed chr() in quotes and the '/&#(\d+);/e' regex throws out an error "Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' .... regexp code on line 1"

Comment: I tested on my local and it works fine :S, let me double check

Comment: If you'll have a chance to take a look at the numericentitieshtml() function that would be great for people that will require to use it (I dont actually need it yet because I am only working with the output data) but thanks for this solution.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you are having? This is very strange as I don't have any problem with my soluttion

Comment: Ok this is strange I dont have this error anymore :/ the error was "Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' ..... "

Answer (score 2):

Following the accepted answer example and the associated comments about deprecation warnings of the "e" flag, here is an updated and multi-byte compatible function to encode a string special characters to their HTML Entities in Decimal notation:

```php
function htmlnumericentities($string) {
    return mb_ereg_replace_callback('[^!-%\x27-;=?-~ ]', function($matches) {
        return '&#'.mb_ord($matches[0]).';';
    }, $string);
}
```

You will need MB String of course.

For example `Dès 67,57 €` will be transformed to `D&#232;s 67,57&#160;&#8364;`.